# How can I create a computed field in an index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I compute a new field for an existing index in Elastic Search?

I have these requirements for the computed field:

- It should be computed and stored together with the other fields, not computed dynamically.
- It should be computed for all historic records, not just new records coming in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the new [subfield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) in your mapping then run an [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) query on your index. That will index the new subfield for your existing data.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Will this work for new documents coming in (as in the field will be computed for each new document), or is it a one-time-only thing?

Comment: @GerardoFigueroa the update by query will just reindex your document (aka apply the new mapping). So new document will automatically have those new subfields.